# mysql 'access denied' error - different behaviour in different machines

Tags: mysql, sql

In our software, I am using some scripts that execute mysql queries.

```
mysql -s "<<query>>
```

Until recently, it was working fine. But now, it is throwing

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

But when i update my script to

```
mysql -uroot -pxxxx -s "<<query>>
```

it works fine.

But when i installed the same software in a different server (linux - same version).

```
mysql -s "<<query>>
```

is working fine in this machine.

What is the reason for the different behavior in different m/c? Is it because of any system configuration?

Comment: Are you remotely accessing your MySQL server?

Comment: Am doing ssh to that m/c and did these things.

Comment: Can you try the same without the -pxxx parameter? mysql -uroot -pxxxx -s <<query>>

Comment: I tried installing again. I am getting the same 'access denied' error,

Comment: I found the reason, there was different values for password for the root user in the two servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, there was different values for password for the root user in the two servers.